# Connecting Samsung Galaxy Tab S6 to HDMI without activating Dex

Tags: samsung, hdmi, samsung-dex, samsung-galaxy-tab-s-6

I own a Samsung Galaxy Tab S6, and it's quite good... except for Samsung's software, which I would qualify as bloatware without hesitation.

I bought a cable that is able to move signal from USB-C ports to HDMI ports, and I connected my tablet to my TV using that cable.

The problem arrives when Samsung, in all its wisdom, refuses to just stream my screen, and insists on starting this Frankenstein thing of Dex. Even if the idea seems good, its execution is very poor, and all the software running on it becomes highly unstable, crashing all the time (when it does not have any problems running in basic mode).

And that's why I'm looking for some way to send my tablet screen to my TV while avoiding to activate Dex.

As an extra, I also considered using something like Chromecast Ultra, and in fact I did, but its streaming quality is just a disaster, and looses a lot of quality (hence my intention to go with simple cables).

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it depends more on the TV than on the tablet itself.
In my particular case, I had to select the specific input source in the TV, and only then the tablet sends the image without trying to run in Dex mode.

To summarize, I had these connection methods:

- Google Chromecast Ultra: relatively low latency, but very bad quality image for anything not being Netflix or Youtube.
- Google/Samsung Smart View: it sends the image via bluetooth, with higher quality than what we have in Chromecast Ultra, but with much higher latency. Unacceptable for videogames.
- USB-C -> HDMI "out of the box": The Dex mode takes control, leading to unstable applications.
- USB-C -> HDMI, but controlling the input source from the TV: What I wanted.

I hope this might be useful for someone else.
Best regards.

Comment: I am sorry but this answer does not make sense to me. To see the HDMI signal you always have to select the matching HDMI input channel in the TV.

Comment: Not really, Dex took control, I just plugged the cable, and I was able to screencast the tablet to the TV, without having to change the configured input there (the default was pointing to another device). Probably the fact that the two devices are from Samsung enabled the possibility for non-standard behaviours.

Comment: I want to do the same thing but don't want to use Chromecast/Smart View because of the latency. What cable do you use to make it work? Just a standard USB-C to HDMI one or do you need the official Samsung Dex one?

Comment: I did not need the Samsung Dex (I mean, I did not need any special hardware)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem while trying to use my TV to have a "messenger" meeting dex kept automatically starting even when I turned it off

Go into settings on your tablet click on the writing "Samsung DEX" below the dex symbol then go to "details" and disable "auto start when Hdmi is connected"

Answer (score 0):

Dex is bound to display link to USB-C. You can truly deactivate Dex if you use a USB-C display output. Because it is linked to a USB plug-and-play detection, you can share the display without Dex only on Wi-Fi.

Dex is more than just a launcher. It switches the Android display and also kernel to support multitasking and multi-screen output. y run Dex always on because it adds additional drives support as LAN connection, hardware keyboard, trackpad, etc. on fex the CPU scheduler runs at a high rate. Take an example the Android for PC which has similar characteristics.